# Installing Windows8 as a Guest OS, all i get is a windows logo and black screen, any suggestions?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8

Windows 8, does the initial install, then says, system must restart.

Once it doesn't it just shows Windows in white, with an all black background.  And just sits there.

Screenshot:
[image]

I tried turning off the guest, and turning it back on.  After about 5 attempts, it says the os has failed to load to many times, and you need to use recovery tools.

Im not sure why, every guide says its easy.  Any ideas?

Comment: Wait for Oracle to Improve the Windows 8 compatibility in Virtualbox.

Comment: It works fine for me, but I had to enable AMD-V or Intel-Vt

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the chipset in the VMs system settings to ICH9. I have had VMs that could not boot under the default PIIX3 setting.